# XCode 4.4.1 and iOS 4.2 device orientation issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, orientation

I know this has been asked a lot of times but still can't get it working.

I want my app only to be available in landscape mode, in the GUI part of my XCode project I've unselected both portrait modes and only the two landscape modes are active. I checked my plist and under Supported Orientations only the two landscape ones are there.

But none the less when I run my app on my iPod running 4.2 firmware I can rotate my app to be in portrait mode.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted an answer which was completely wrong :P which is now removed but it did help me find the correct answer; I replaced:

```
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
```

In my ViewController.m with:

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
```

So thanks to the poster who deleted their post! It helped me find the correct answer.

Comment: `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that definitely is a much better way of doing it.